# "Heel" as a name of the part of a leg and "heel" as a name of the part of a women's shoes

Tags: word-choice

As a dictionary says the word "heel" has general meaning to leg's heel and shoes' heel, so when I talk about 'Heel' as a name of the part of a leg what more exact word can I use? The same question is to a name of the part of a women's shoes.

Comment: You still use *heel*. Context will take care of the rest.

Comment: It would depend on the context. In some health and exercise contexts (e.g. an article on running) you could call the body part the *tarsus*.  And "the heel of the shoe" would disambiguate for the footwear.

Answer (score 3):

Context makes it clear. If absolutely necessary you can say "shoe's heel" or "foot's heel", or similar.

> I'm wearing a cast because I dropped a stone on my foot. My heel and ankle were crushed.  Incredibly, the heel of my shoe didn't break.

Context makes the first reference "heel" completely clear. In this artificial situation the second reference to "heel" would be unclear if not written with "of my shoe".